Platform Events designed to be Short Messages? Better to Query on Receiver?
In our a project, after updating a Quote Object in salesforce, we want to gather some related Account Information, Contacts, Multiple Quote Line Items, etc and send into Platform EventBus.
However, a similar question regarding nested child objects. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/331340/131964
Both of these are not ideal options.
(a) Either our Nested Child object be a string, which cannot exceed a character limit
(b) or system would need send multiple events
Third option , is have the receiver query all the correlated data using a simple QuoteId.
Just curious, are Salesforce Platform Publisher Sender events even designed and purposed to send nested objects? Or are platform events are designed to be short and succinct? Does Salesforce recommend rather getting all the nested child related objects in the Receiver/Subscriber using a keyId reference?

Given that platform event delivery is not guaranteed, I personally do not believe they should be used to hold unique or critical data and instead should be treated as a way to initiate async processing or to simply notify an external system to perform some polling action.

hi @PhilW thanks, feel free to write as possible answer, thanks

https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/trigger-automation is a good read

As per the documentation, platform event delivery is not guaranteed:

In rare cases, the event message might not be persisted in the distributed system during the initial or subsequent attempts. This means that the events aren’t delivered to subscribers, and they aren’t recoverable.

As such I would never place unique data in a platform event. Instead I would store this data in normal objects in the database and simply use platform events to trigger asynchronous processing or to notify external systems that there is data they could query to process (through standard or custom REST or SOAP APIs).

ok thanks, Our Platform event publisher will triggered on Quote_Update trigger, so we will have a record of what will be sent, we can query on receiver then

If the data grows in size or complexity, you should evaluate alternatives such as sending minimal data in the event and relying on queries to retrieve detailed information.
Also make sure your payload doesnt exceed the 1MB limit based on the documentation.
Resource:
Salesforce Platform Event Limits

Only if your application can live with losing some of these events and their data.

ok thanks, did you have any resources/documentation for this answer? appreciate it

The above answer is based on the limits and the restrictions that are imposed by the platform moving large data volumes would not be a good architectural practice as it would lead to poor performance as well as governor limit hits. You can refer to the Salesforce documentation on the limits of Platform events to get some more idea
